# How can I clip a Shape with another Shape in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to clip the red square with the green half-circle. I tried .mask and .clipShape but
i can't get this to work. Can someone share how its done please?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestEndBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1.0)
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                    .offset(x: -250)
                    
        }
    }
}

struct TestEndBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestEndBarView()
    }
}
```

[image: A red square with a green half circle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with using `eoFill` like in the code:

---

[image]

---

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        CustomShape()
            .fill(Color.purple, style: FillStyle(eoFill: true, antialiased: true))
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .shadow(radius: 10.0)
 
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.height/2, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: true)
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))
 
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: oh great thanks. i am attaching my own code down below as well. maybe also useful for someone who stumbles on this question in the future.

Comment: @AndiAna: I see your code, you hard coded values that would not re usable, also you created Rect with Lines, you can use Rect so easy!

Comment: i changed it to use rect.width etc. . yeah i needed to amend the shape further and thinking in terms of the basic lines is sometimes easier than with the shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `struct` that conforms to `Shape`.

Implement `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path`

Create a `Path`. Add the rectangle, then the circle.

Fill the shape with [isEOFilled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fillstyle/iseofilled) set to `true`

Answer (score 0):

My code is this basic one. Maybe someone finds this useful so i am attaching it here as well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestEndBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BoxCutOut()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    
        }
    }
}

struct TestEndBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestEndBarView()
    }
}

struct BoxCutOut: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width, y:0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width, y:rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:rect.height))
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height/2), radius: rect.height/2, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true )
        }
    }
}
```